# Append data with ogr2ogr when target has two geometry columns

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am running the following command:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -update -append --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=yyyy password=***** user=zzz" "C:\xxx.gpkg" -where "Owner_ID in (89061,720883,713699,88665,8985008,708759,713696,721202,721203,715717,9394015,9394258,9393828,720197,719592,721195,718608,9379306)" -lco LAUNDER=YES -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nln schema.existing_table -a_srs EPSG:27700
```

The attribute columns in the table have the same names (albeit in caps) but the PG table has more columns

All the attributes are copied across correctly, but I can't work out how to specify where the geometry should go as there are two geometry columns in the PostGIS table. I don't think any of the layer creation options work because it's not actually creating a layer.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-sql` expression with `-dialect spatialite` to rename the geometry field to the appropriate column name (and to apply the filter):

```
ogr2ogr.exe -update -append --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=yyyy password=***** user=zzz" "C:\xxx.gpkg" -lco LAUNDER=YES -nln schema.existing_table -a_srs EPSG:27700 -sql "SELECT *, <source_geom_column_name> AS <target_geom_column_name> FROM <source_table_name> WHERE Owner_ID in (89061,720883,713699,88665,8985008,708759,713696,721202,721203,715717,9394015,9394258,9393828,720197,719592,721195,718608,9379306)"
```

Note that `SELECT *, <source_geom_column_name> ...` only works if the name is different from *any* of the target geometry column names; you'd have to specify the complete column list if it matches (the probably wrong) `<target_geom_column_name>`, or both will get filled

Comment: That mostly works, but I found I had to spell out all the columns for some reason and not add a duplicate at the end as you have done here (despite the source columns and all columns in the target geometry being different) - suspect something to do with the number of columns

Comment: So this worked: `ogr2ogr.exe -update -append --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=yyyy password=**** user=zzzz" "C:/mydata.gpkg" -sql "SELECT m.\"fid\", m.\"geom\" as geom_snake, ........" FROM \"my_dataset\" m WHERE \"Owner_ID\" in (89061,720883,713699,88665,8985008,708759,713696,721202,721203,715717,9394015,9394258,9393828,720197,719592,721195,718608,9379306)" -nln schema.existing_table`

Comment: This didn't: `ogr2ogr.exe -update -append --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=yyyy password=**** user=zzzz" "C:/mydata.gpkg" -sql "SELECT *, geom as geom_snake FROM \"my_dataset\" WHERE \"Owner_ID\" in (89061,720883,713699,88665,8985008,708759,713696,721202,721203,715717,9394015,9394258,9393828,720197,719592,721195,718608,9379306)" -nln util_new.tw_all_new_xdisp_input`

Comment: Might be version specific? Not sure, works for me. Btw. you can wrap the option strings within `'` and use `"` without escaping.